# iOS - relations between views

Tags: ios, subviews

I'm just learning the iOS, so my question is very basic... I've read a lot about organizing subviews in the application, but there are so many things there, that I would like to ask you if I've understood it well...

The main part of the app is a window. ViewController manages only one view. In a window I can set the `rootViewController`. This controller manages the view during entire application workflow. Next I can create some subviews, connect these subviews to the main view (parent) using outlets, and the when instatiating `rootViewController` I can add my subviews by `:addSubview` method. Am I right more or less?

And one question more... Should each subview be managed by a dedicated ViewController (then, the parent has outlets to these controllers) or I can change the subviews state directly from parent ViewController?

And short example:

I would like to create an iPad app which has (both visible at a time): 
  - at the top: short form and button (user enters some data and clicks "Save" button)
  - at the bottom: a table displaying provided values

So:

I can create one main view, and two subviews (for form and table). Each time I add some values table will be refreshed using the parent controller... Does it make sense?

**It you see that I understand something wrong, please tell me what should I read about.**

Thanks for patience.

Answer (score 1):

`rootViewController` is the starting point for your application and you can create more `viewController` and add subviews on the `viewController` depending on your needs for application.

> I would like to create an iPad app which has (both visible at a time): - at the top: short form and button (user enters some data and clicks "Save" button) - at the bottom: a table displaying provided values

you can create `UITableView` & `UIButton` as `subView`  to the `UiViewController`(will be Owner of the subviews) or any other subviews like labels,textfields etc.

Answer (score 1):

iOS follows MVC pattern.

The controller class is a manager which binds data to the view. So you can have separate classes for your view and data.

Your understanding is right. To achieve the things you have mentioned,

1. Create a subclass of UIViewController.
2. Add two subviews to it (TableView and Button). This could be done using xib or programmatically
3. Add the delegate methods of your tableview inside your controller class and set tableview's delegate as your controller class.
4. Add the event for button.

.

Answer (score 0):

The subviews are connected to the files owner that is the `viewcontroller`..not the parentview.